# Obtener valores de Form Data Js

Tags: javascript, post

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
console.log("hola");
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
  $.post("demo_test_post.asp",
  {
    name: "Donald Duck",
    city: "Duckburg"
  },
 function(data,status){
   alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
 });
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Al ejecutarlo, obtengo el siguiente Form Data:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es acceder a los campos del Form Data con JS. Lo podre hacer?

Muchas gracias

Comment: No dupliques preguntas, simplemente sigue las indicaciones de la gente que te intenta guiar en los comentarios, tu pregunta original era [Recuperar campo de Form Data con JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/327291/recuperar-campo-de-form-data-con-javascript). Deberías de editar una de las 2 preguntas y la otra eliminarla

Comment: Por otro lado, ese `formData` no es lo que te está devolviendo si no lo que está enviando. En el `$.post` estás indicando lo siguiente: `name: "Donald Duck", city: "Duckburg"`. Tu estás mirando la pestaña **headers** del navegador, la respuesta la puedes ver en la pestaña **preview** o la de **response**